# Ionic Input Closes App and Doesn't Display Numeric Pad

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I have form that I have been working on and testing in both iPhone and Android device. Android devices seem to work just fine. How it is suppose to operate is that when the user clicks on the input box, the numeric pad shows, not the text keyboard. This does not happen on iPhone. The other part to this is that on the iPhone, the app will close when the textbox is clicked for the first time when the app loads or if you click rage on it. I am using the Ionic framework.

```
<form name="prices">
    <div class="list" ng-controller="ReportPrice">
        <div class="item item-input-inset">
            <span class="input-label">Regular</span>
            <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                <input style="font-size: 30px; height: 50px" name="regButton" ng-init="inputIdReg='regButton';"
                       ng-attr-id="inputId" type="tel" ng-change="changeButton(inputIdReg)"
                       ng-model="price.regPrice" placeholder="-.--" pattern="[0-9]*"
                       inputmode="numeric">
            </label>
            <button ng-class="regButton" ng-click="reportPrice(1, price)">
                {{ regButtonText }}
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-input-inset">
            <span class="input-label">Mid Grade</span>
            <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                <input style="font-size: 30px; height: 50px" ng-init="inputIdMid='midButton';"
                       id="midPriceText" type="tel" ng-change="changeButton(inputIdMid)" 
                       ng-model="price.midPrice" placeholder="-.--" pattern="[0-9]*"
                       inputmode="numeric">
            </label>


            <button ng-class="midButton" ng-click="reportPrice(2, price)">
                {{ midButtonText }}
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-input-inset">
            <span class="input-label">Premium</span>
            <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                <input style="font-size: 30px; height: 50px" ng-init="inputIdPre='preButton';"
                       id="prePriceText" type="tel" ng-change="changeButton(inputIdPre)" 
                       ng-model="price.prePrice" placeholder="-.--" pattern="[0-9]*"
                       inputmode="numeric">
            </label>


            <button ng-class="preButton" ng-click="reportPrice(3, price)">
                {{ preButtonText }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: try <input  type="number" > instead of inputmode="numeric"

Answer (score 0):

I removed `inputmode="numeric"` and `pattern="[0-9*]"` which showed the number pad. I kept `type="tel"`

On a side note, this also seems to have clear the issue when the input box was tapped, the app would close. I will continue to monitored this and see what happens.